# PDO insert only one record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to overcome this problem for a while now and i need your help on this.

The code on the below only insert one record in mysql table and only one. Data from html forms are posted very well but it simple doesn't record more than once. I also use phpmyadmin and i don't know what is the problem. I'd be appriciated if you could help me.

Here is the code:

```
   try {

    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
    $STH1 = $DBH->query("SELECT isim, adet, kategori 
                             FROM stock 
                             WHERE isim = '$isim' AND kategori = '$kategori'");
    $STH1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($STH1->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "There is no such record";
    }
    else {

        $STH2 = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO outgoing 
                                       (isim, adet, nereye, cikis_tarih, kategori) 
                                       values 
                                       (:isim, :adet, :nereye, :cikis_tarih, :kategori)");
        $STH2->bindParam(':isim', $isim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH2->bindParam(':adet', $adet, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH2->bindParam(':nereye', $nereye, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH2->bindParam(':cikis_tarih', $cikis_tarih, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH2->bindParam(':kategori', $kategori, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH2->execute();

    }    

}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: And where are your variables coming from? `$isim` etc. None have been defined.

Comment: from .php page `$isim=$_POST['isim'];`

Comment: Are those variables (`$isim` etc) arrays or 'just' variables? Because if you want to insert multiple you should put the `bindparam` and `execute` in some loop that iterates over the values you want to input.

Comment: And are all your form elements `named`? I.e.: `<input type="text" name="isim">` etc.?

Comment: Those are simple variables.

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to execute as an array. I.e.: `execute(array(':isim'=>$isim,':adet'=>$adet...`

Comment: Yeah, form element names are the same.

Comment: I am not sure that's the problem because i copyied this from a working  code of mine, but i will think about it

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. @billwild

Comment: That first query needs to be re-written to use placeholders like the second does because it's highly probable you've got a huge [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: @tadman, Thank you, i am just testing it to see if i can do it, nothing serious.

Comment: @billwild "Nothing serious" is the worst excuse ever an is probably the same thing said before the infamous [Sony hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Network_outage#Sony_Pictures_Entertainment_website_hacking). Do not, ever, for any reason leave code this hazardously bad in your code base. Things like this have a way of worming their way into production without you realizing. It's like leaving a loaded gun on the table. If you do it right the first time, which isn't even hard, you'll be guaranteed that sort of thing won't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
$STH2->bindParam(':isim', $isim, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH2->bindParam(':adet', $adet, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH2->bindParam(':nereye', $nereye, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH2->bindParam(':cikis_tarih', $cikis_tarih, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH2->bindParam(':kategori', $kategori, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH2->execute();
```

Execute it through an array:

```
$STH2->execute(array(':isim'=>$isim,
                                ':adet'=>$adet,
                                ':nereye'=>$nereye,
                                ':cikis_tarih'=>$cikis_tarih,
                                ':kategori'=>$kategori));
```

Comment: I'll try this but i need time

Comment: Do all your columns exist and no typos, or spaces? Plus make sure none of them have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` set to them. I use this type of method all the time, and I wouldn't have posted this, if I knew it didn't work. So, something else is causing this. @billwild

Comment: Only `AUTO_INCREMENT` field is `id`. But i think you might be right because i have used this on other pages as well and it is working. It should be something about phpmyadmin. I try to delete recreate all the databa then. Thanks a lot.